# How to use firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm a beginner in Flutter, I want to use firebase in my flutter app, I run my app on chrome because the emulator does not work, I have configured the `build.gradle` file, and the `pubspec.yaml`, when I run my app I have an error saying:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'. 
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...            154.8s
Failed to compile application.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Comment: Please describe why this works

Answer (score 0):

for now use this versions:

```
  firebase_analytics:
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  cloud_firestore: 
  cloud_functions: 
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```